# How to properly use Magit Fixup?

Tags: magit, git

I am trying to use the `Fixup` feature on Magit. I will list a recipe to what it is happening:

(i) - I have a project under version control.

(ii) - My first commit is:

```lisp
1f61d09 * first commit: add file
```

The content is:

```lisp
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
random-stack-overflow-questions/fixup-magit-test.txt | 1 +

new file   random-stack-overflow-questions/fixup-magit-test.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+just a test
```

(iii) - My second commit is:

```lisp
a503541 * second commit: changing the original file.
```

And the diff shows:

```lisp
modified   random-stack-overflow-questions/fixup-magit-test.txt
@@ -1 +1,3 @@
 just a test
+
+just another test
```

(iv) - Then, I decided to change the content of my first commit. I **could** do a new commit, then an interactive rebase, and use it to change the order of the commits moving the third/last commit to be before the second and squashed with the first.

Instead, I decided to use the feature **Fixup** - since it seems to be designed for situations like this.

Hence, I did the following change:

```lisp
modified   random-stack-overflow-questions/fixup-magit-test.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
-just a test
+just a test FIXED-UP
```

After writing that change on the file, I staged the change, then I pressed `c` to commit and, finally, I pressed **lower case** `f` (not upper case `F`) to `Instant fixup`.

Things do seem to work. Unfortunately, when I pressed `git log`, this is what I see:

```lisp
5f91266 * main fixup! first commit: add file
```

I was **not** expecting the **fixup!** to be on `git log` history. I thought my change would be a *fix up* on the first commit.

Did I miss something? How can I properly use the fix-up feature?

And what can I do now to achieve what I want? Is it necessary to do an interactive rebase to remove `fixup` from the git log history?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>f</kbd> just creates the `fixup!` commit.  You wanted the upper-case <kbd>F</kbd> -- that ("Instant Fixup") is the variant which automatically performs the rebase *after* creating the `fixup!` commit.

You can alternatively use <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> to invoke `git rebase --autosquash` yourself, which is the git option that processes the `squash!` and `fixup!` commit messages (see the man page for details).

Be sure to place point on the commit that you wish to squash into before you start -- Magit will use that as the target by default.